# Installing multiple packages via Nuget by single command

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, nuget

I am using Nuget via Visual Studio's Package Manager Console. For every project I need to add few packages e.g. xunit.contribs, fluentassertions and nsubstitute. To do that I type 3 commands in consolle.

I understand that console is just another powershell host and there should be a way to create a script (kind of Add-Test-Stuff.ps1) that will add several packages at once. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I typically define my packages in arrays and execute them using a foreach loop

```
$angular = "AngularJS.Animate", "AngularJS.Core", "AngularJS.Locale", "AngularJS.Resource", "AngularJS.Route", "AngularJS.Sanitize", "AngularJS.Touch"
$angular | foreach {Install-Package $_}
```

This can also be written as a one-liner

```
"AngularJS.Animate", "AngularJS.Core", "AngularJS.Locale", "AngularJS.Resource", "AngularJS.Route", "AngularJS.Sanitize", "AngularJS.Touch" | foreach {Install-Package $_}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not direct answer to you question, sorry. But I've seen very nice practive adopted for Code52 [IdeaStrike](https://github.com/Code52/Ideastrike) project.

They do not have any packages included in source control, instead they will be installed during first build of solution and downloaded automatically, depending on packages.config

The details of configuration are here:

[Using NuGet without committing packages to source control](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages#Using_NuGet_without_committing_packages_to_source_control)

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to add them to `packages.config` somehow. I am wondering ho to do that in the fastest way :)

Answer (score 1):

Put any script to your solution directory and you will be able to execute it from Package Manager Console.

Comment: OK, is it possible to put script to some home folder?

Comment: You can put it anywere in PATH. But I think this script is project specific. Not sure why to keep it somewhere else.

Comment: well, I want to add the same set of packages to all my test projects