# nuget.exe install not updating packages.config (or .csproj)?

Tags: c#, mono, nuget

While trying to get a nuget build workflow working on Linux/mono, I've noticed an odd thing.

Being on Linux, I cannot use the nuget Visual Studio plugin or the Powershell console, but I have the nuget.exe command-line utility. This utility has an "install" command which properly fetches packages and places them in my packages directory.

However, nuget.exe's install (as opposed to the Visual Studio install) doesn't appear to update packages.config with the packages it added, nor does it add project references to my .csproj. The latter is less important (I can do it manually), since the packages.config needs to contain recursive dependencies as well I can't do it manually...

Has anyone else tried to install new packages solely using nuget.exe or has any insight into this? Am I barking up the wrong tree entirely?

Comment: Please fire bug reports to NuGet, http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Comment: Cross-posted this to the nuget codeplex forum, interesting discussion there: http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/399714

Comment: Thanks for pasting the link. It is an interesting read. How I hope one of the developers can stay enough on Linux + Mono to make sure compatibility issues are minimal, but that's just my imagination.

Comment: Me too... according to a comment it seems like the fix shouldn't be too hard, I might take a look at this. Then of course there's monodevelop nuget support :)

Comment: The nuget.exe install command is really a misnomer. It should be called restore command. As you, plus many other people, found to their unpleasant surprise, nuget.exe install command only restores packages, it does not install package into projects.

Answer (score 4):

As it currently (Nuget 2.8.1) stands, this is still not possible and a major shortcoming of the nuget command line client, as I see it.

Nuget.exe must be able to install a package and add it to the `packages.config` **with all dependencies** to be usable for anything more than the most simple cases.

I have created an issue, see https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/4258

### Workaround

For the time being, the following approach can be used. Note that it is far from optimal, but at least enables you to use nuget and resolve dependent packages correctly.

1. Resort to managing the `packages.config` manually. Add the packages you need, but omit their dependencies. Note that this is different from "ordinary" `packages.config` files, which do list the dependencies as well.
2. Use a script to walk the `packages.config` and issue a `nuget install <package-id> -Version <version>` for each package. This will install the package and its dependencies.

Comment: `nuget install` currently does not update the project file. Using `nuget install` to download the NuGet packages will work if you do not need the project file to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better workaround is to use [the technique described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36820607/2475012) to generate a PCM command that will install multiple packages in one go.

Here's a small proof of concept that copies the final command to the clipboard:

```
param([string[]]$dependencies)

$command = "";

foreach($dependency in $dependencies) 
{
    $name = $item.Name
    if($dependency)
    {
        $command += ('"{0}", ' -f $dependency)
    }
}

$command = $command.Substring(0, $command.Length - 2) + " | foreach {Install-Package `$_}"
$command | Set-Clipboard
```