# How do I correctly install nuget packages outside of VS and keep track of them?

Tags: nuget, build-process

I'm trying to use nuget.exe outside of Visual Studio as part of our build infrastructure. The idea is that the various build tools are fetched by a bootstrapper script that initializes a working copy. The bootstrapper does this by using a file that specifies the required tools and their version.

### Broken approach 1 - use manually edited `packages.config`

At first, it seemed like a good idea to keep a manually edited `packages.config` file and use `nuget restore` to install them during bootstrapping. However, this does not work for tools that have dependencies, unless I list every single dependency in the `packages.config` as well, a much to arduous approach to be feasible, because I found no easy way to recursively find all dependencies of a package.

See also [using nuget.exe commandline to install dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17187725/219187) .

### Broken approach 2 - use `nuget install` to update `packages.config`

The second idea was then to use `nuget install` to install the packages, and let that command update the `packages.config`, very similar to the Install-Package cmdlet in the package manager console. But, surprisingly, `nuget install` does not support this! It either takes a `packages.config` or a package ID as parameter, but I found no way to update the `packages.config` with the new package and its dependencies.

This problem can also be found in another (two year old) SO question, see [nuget.exe install not updating packages.config (or .csproj)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12930868/219187).

### Is there a working (and non-hacky) approach at all?

This must be a problem that many people face when using nuget outside of VS, so what is the best approach in that case?

Of course, I could just parse the `packages.config` and emit a `nuget install` for each package, but I really don't want to re-invent the dependency management part of nuget, this is what I'm using nuget for in the first place. So I'm left with the feeling that either an `-WithDependencies` switch on `nuget restore` or an `-UpdatePackagesConfig` switch on `nuget install` is missing...

Note that there are other SO questions regarding the broken approaches described above. What I'd like to know it what the best approach is to solve the root problem, i.e. manage packages with dependencies outside of VS.

Answer (score 2):

`nuget install` does not currently make changes to the project file.

`nuget install` can be used to either restore the NuGet packages listed in a packages.config file or download and extract them.

If you do not need the project being modified then your solution of reading the packages in the packages.config file and calling `nuget install` seems like a reasonable approach.

If you need the project to be modified then you could look at one of the following:

1. [Ripple](http://fubuworld.com/ripple/index/) - a command line tool that adds extra features to NuGet. It has a `ripple install` command line which is similar to `nuget install` but it also updates the project file. It has a lot of other features for supporting build servers so this might be a good fit.
2. [NuGet packages outside of Visual Studio with SharpDevelop](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2011/06/12/InstallingNuGetPackagesOutsideVisualStudio.aspx) - this was an experiment I put together to see whether full NuGet support could be achieved, including PowerShell scripts, from the command line without using Visual Studio. It uses PowerShell and quite a bit of SharpDevelop.
3. Customise NuGet.exe to do what you need. `nuget update`, for example, does modify the project file, at least for file references, but will not run PowerShell scripts. So you could take the NuGet.exe source code and extend it.

Of the above only 3) would give you exactly what you need. The other two would require a bit of work to read the packages from the packages.config file or some other list and then install them.

Comment: I do not have a project file that I need to update. See the end of my question or the comments to Kilimans answers on why I think that calling creating a script to walk the packages.config is a hack.

Comment: You cannot use the  Package Manager Console outside of Visual Studio. Option 2) is about the closest you can get. It provides the NuGet PowerShell cmdlets but directly from the PowerShell console on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [Why does the nuget command line tool not follow dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271727/why-does-the-nuget-command-line-tool-not-follow-dependencies/23280252)

`nuget install My.Package.Id` will follow dependencies. However, if you want to install multiple packages, you will need to create a batch file with a separate `nuget install` command for each package. These are top-level packages. You don't need to "install" the dependencies, as they will get downloaded automatically.

If you ultimately want a `packages.config` file, I imagine you can generate one by enumerating all the packages that were downloaded. However, you would have to take care not to include multiple versions of the same package.

Comment: Yes, that's the workaround that I've implemented. So there really doesn't seem to be a proper way to do this. With this approach, nuget has no possibility to perform overall package analysis (e.g. find conflicting dependencies).

Comment: That's just a limitation of the nuget command line tool. As I said before, the command line is basically used to download packages, not truly install them. For that, it's better to use the NuGet GUI or Package Manage console. NuGet does have a Package Visualizer tool http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/package-visualizer

Comment: Ok, so it is possible to use the Package Manager Console outside of VS? Could you give me a hint on how to do that? Google does not seem to know much about it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that how **nuget 3** works with **project.json** files may do what you are looking for. Essentially my understanding is that the unit of dependency becomes the *package* and not necessarily individual assemblies. From what I recall, the idea is the have only one place to manage these types of package references which the project (IDE/Editor), package manager, and other command line tools can use.

What I don't understand and feel somewhat frustrated about is that it appears that the [project.json concept is being canceled](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/). I don't know if plans are to reintroduce it at anytime in the future. In the mean time I keep on hearing updated info on tooling that takes advantage of project.json such as nuget so where you can actually rely on this is something that is unclear to me at this point.